# iOS UITableView and Master-Detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, insert, master-detail

I am working on a Master-Detail like app (for both iPhone and iPad) and I can't reproduce the same behavior of the Notes native app while inserting new item. Besides, I haven't found any interesting help on Google. On insertion I want to redirect the user to the detail view of the newly inserted item. I tried to call the selectRowAtIndexPath: in the didChangeObject: method of the controller like this :

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            break;
```

But nothing happens... may be because the newly inserted item didn't have the time to appear in the table view?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add [tableView reloadData]:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

**Edit**:

`scrollToRowAtIndexPath` only highlights the cell, and won't fire `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, try to manually call it by:

```
[tableView.delegate tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Yes the row is successfully inserted, but the detail view does not come

Comment: Ah you need to fire the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate: try this after selectRowAtIndexPath [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: It works perfectly on iPad (just by using [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];) but not on iPhone probably because of didSelectRowAtIndexPath: implementation, it does something only for the iPad. For the iPhone it is based on storyboard segues, I thing I have to perform a segue manually without forgetting to update the detailItem ivar, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Nice, for segue you can put the action in: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender.

Comment: In prepareForSegue: Apple already did the job, but I don't know how to perform the segue programmatically, [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self] will not set detailItem, any idea? Anyway thank you for your help

Comment: If this was helpful, please consider to check the answer as accepted, for firing the segue programmatically you can put another question. cheers.